# add config from a bundle

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I would like to add my bundle config.yml to the app/config/config.yml

I found a way via the imports.

I wanted to write this :

```
imports:
  - { resource: parameters.yml }
  - { resource: security.yml }
  name_of_my_bundle:
    - { resource: @MyBundle/Resources/Config/config.yml}
```

but it does not work...

How should I write it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indentation is important in yml. For 'imports', you don't need to specify a bundle name at all.

```
imports:
  - { resource: parameters.yml }
  - { resource: security.yml }
  - { resource: @MyBundle/Resources/Config/config.yml}
```